# MySQL: How to only select rows where 'set' column has all the values / none of the values

Tags: mysql

I have a SET data type column in my MySQL table called `category_list` that can contain one or more of the following values: `Category 1`, `Category 2`.

**First Question:**

To return rows where both categories have been selected, I use:

```
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Category 1', category_list) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('Category 2', category_list) > 0"
```

This works fine. However when I have many categories this statement becomes large.  Is there an easier/better way to select rows for which ALL the categories have been selected?

**Second question:**

To return rows where NONE of the categories have been selected, I use this query:

```
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('XYZ', category_list) = 0"
```

I make sure that `XYZ` is not a possible value in the SET.

This also works ok, however if I add the value `XYZ` to the SET at a later time, then all these queries obviously will break.

Is there an easier/better way to select only those rows where the set column has no value?